# Filter Content Area Items

Tags: episerver

I have a list of ContentArea items on a particular block.

The structure of the block is as follows:

Contact Block

```
Contact Item Block 1
Contact Item Block 2
```

This main Contact block is added on a page.The approx. contact items in a single contact block is around 900+.
I need to get the contact items on my UI but before I get it,I need to include some filters to it so that the final content area items are based on the filter & not all of the 900+ items.

I have added the below query which works fine but the problem here is, it gets all the Contact Items first & then apply filters which is why it takes a lot of time more like in minutes.

```
var contactItems = currentBlock.ContactItemContentArea.FilteredItems
                            .Select(contentItem => _contentRepository.Get<ContactItemBlock>(contentItem.ContentLink))
                            .Where(item => item.Area == "Management" && item.Department == "Finance" && item.Location == "US");
```

Is there a more efficient way to filter these contentarea items ?

Regards.

Comment: That really shouldn't take _minutes_, at least not after initial startup, as the content items will be cached. Does it take that long every time?

Are you using DXP (or Search & Navigation)? If so, you may get better performance using the search index.

Comment: Thanks for thr response Ted.To answer your question,It's only on the initial load that it takes around 5-6mins & the subsequent search results are quick.But this long wait even on the initial load is not a good user experience & so I am looking for an alternate optimized query filtering without using Search service.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a more efficient way to do this. The bottle neck lies in this line of code:

```
.Select(contentItem => _contentRepository.Get<ContactItemBlock>(contentItem.ContentLink))
```

What happens here is that "for each `contentItem`, get me that item from the database". 900+ items means 900+ database calls. Each database call has an overhead - the time it takes for the request to reach the database server and the time it takes for the result to come back from the database server. What you can do here to improve performance is to use `contentLoader.GetItems(currentBlock.ContactItemContentArea.FilteredItems)` which is equal to "get me these items", thus resulting in the overhead one time. 900+ items means one database call unless the implementation of the method batches the requests under the hood but this is not something you should have to take into consideration (just a disclaimer). You can then type the items using the LINQ methods `Cast<ContactItemBlock>()` or `OfType<ContactItemBlock>()` and then apply your Where clause for additional filtering. For clarity, your code should look something like this:

```
var contactItems = _contentRepository.GetItems(currentBlock.ContactItemContentArea.FilteredItems)
    .OfType<ContactItemBlock>()
    .Where(item => item.Area == "Management" && item.Department == "Finance" && item.Location == "US");
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Marcus. One of the issue was the structure for which I have altered the structure of the block hierarchy & implemented the same in method batches that made a drastic improvement in performance.